# How to seed foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-migrations

i am using spatie/laravel-permission package for roles and permissions

but getting problem in seed permanent role and permission here is database list link

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/database/migrations/create_permission_tables.php.stub

and i make these dataseeder for seeding

```
 $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
 $this->call(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
 $this->call(RolesTableSeeder::class);
 $this->call(RolehaspermissionTableSeeder::class);
 $this->call(ModelhasrolesTableSeeder::class);
```

permissiontableseeder

```
DB::table('roles')->insert([
'name' => 'Administrator',
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
```

RoleTableSeeder

```
DB::table('roles')->insert([
'name' => 'Admin',
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
```

RolehaspermissionTableSeeder

```
DB::table('role_has_permissions')->insert([
'permission_id' => '1',
'role_id' => '1',
]);
```

ModelhasrolesTableSeeder

```
DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert([
'role_id' => '1',
'model_id' => '1',
'model_type' => 'App\User',
]);
```

here is screenshot of error

> http://prntscr.com/h83ttx

Help me for seed this thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide us a screenshot of the error that appears when you try to seed?

Comment: yes sure here is screenshot of error

http://prntscr.com/h83ttx

@AhmedEssam

Comment: Use fresh instead of refresh

Comment: ohh i found the error i 
permissiontableseeder

DB::table('roles')->insert([
'name' => 'Administrator',
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
i forgot to change roles to permissions and now its working fine

Comment: please post this spell mistake than i can check on that answer thanks

Comment: @berkaykılıç can u post this answer i wront below same than i can click on check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check table name

```
DB::table('roles')->insert([
'name' => 'Administrator',
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
```

on permissionstableseeder

this should be like this

```
DB::table('permissions')->insert([
'name' => 'Administrator',
'guard_name' => 'web',
]);
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 5):

We can do like this...

```
$coursesIDs = DB::table('courses')->pluck('id');
$studentsIDs= DB::table('students')->pluck('id');

foreach (range(1,50) as $index) {
        DB::table('course_student')->insert([
            'course_id' => $faker->randomElement($coursesIDs)
            'student_id' => $faker->randomElement($studentsIDs)
        ]);
}
```